# Laravel 5.4 belongsToMany - show result in html

Tags: php, laravel

I create a many-to-many relationship, where many projects can be assigned to many users. My problem is that I do not know how to display projects assigned to a given user. . Currently, all available projects are displayed. I created pivot table, where after adding the project I store the project id and user id. This is my code:

User.php

```
 public function projects()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Project')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

Project.php

```
 public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

ProjectsController.php

```
public function projects()
    {
        $projects = Project::latest()->get();
        return view('pages.projects')->with('projects', $projects);
    }
```

migrations:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->longText('p_name')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('project_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedInteger('project_id');
            $table->foreign('project_id')->references('id')->on('projects')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: What does your current HTML look like?

Comment: <div class="row">
    @foreach($projects as $project) but this show all projects, not just assigdned to user

Comment: please post the current `view` code

Comment: Try to use something like this:
`foreach($projects as $project) {var_dump($project->users()->get());}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eager load users in your controller:

```
public function projects()
{
    $projects = Project::latest()->with('users')->get();
    return view('pages.projects')->with('projects', $projects);
}
```

In your view:

```
@foreach($projects as $project)
    @foreach($project->users as $user)

    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

If you want to display projects assigned to a user you would do something like:

```
public function projectsByUser($userId)
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($userId);

    $projects = $user->projects;

    return view('pages.projects')->with('projects', $projects);
}
```

and keep the view like:

```
@foreach($projects as $project)

@endforeach
```

Comment: did not work. I would like to see only projects that are assigned in the pivot table for this user, now I'm showing all the projects that are in the database

Comment: But in your controller you getting latest projects not projects by user? Let me modify my answer

Comment: my question is how to take only the projects assigned to a particular user in the controller and show them, and not show all the projects that are in the database

Comment: Please check my modified answer, you will need to pass $userId in order to filter projects by user